# Java BigInteger to byte array equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, biginteger

I'm working on an integration with a partner that uses Java's `BigInteger` to generate a byte array as the key for a simple encryption algorithm. I'm trying to find the equivalent .NET code without much luck.

The Java code they're using is:

```
String keyString = "48B734DA47388C656913C9BF5146E186";
byte key[] = new BigInteger(keyString, 16).toByteArray();
```

which yields the following `byte` array:

```
[72, -73, 52, -38, 71, 56, -116, 101, 105, 19, -55, -65, 81, 70, -31, -122]
```

This alone is troubling because `byte`s in .NET range from 0-255 so the negative values are out of range.

The closest .NET code I came up with is:

```
string keyString = "48B734DA47388C656913C9BF5146E186";
byte[] key = BigInteger.Parse(keyString, NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToByteArray();
```

which yields the following `byte` array:

```
[134, 225, 70, 81, 191, 201, 19, 105, 101, 140, 56, 71, 218, 52, 183, 72]
```

At this point, I'm thinking a .NET equivalent simply isn't possible - especially because of the negative `byte` values.

I look forward to everyone's thoughts.

Comment: Try appending `.Cast<sbyte>().ToArray();` after `ToByteArray()`. Should work.

Comment: `which yields the following byte array` - That is not a byte array. In any case, it is a `System.SByte[]`.

Comment: @HighCore The first byte array is a java `byte` array which are signed values. The second is .Net `byte` array which are not signed values.

Comment: rjygraham, See what this prints `var s = String.Join(",", key.Reverse().Select(x => (sbyte)x).ToArray());`

Comment: OP, do you have any reason not to use `sbyte` instead of `byte`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the LINQ method I4V offered in the comments solves it handily.

```
  sbyte[] key = BigInteger.Parse(keyString, NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToByteArray().Reverse().Select(x => (sbyte)x).ToArray();
```

That will get you the array you want. .NET uses unsigned bytes by default, whereas Java uses signed bytes by default. They have the same bit representation, so, depending on what you're doing with it, it may not actually matter which one is used, but, if you want a truly equivalent output in .NET, you'll need to use sbytes instead of bytes, as simply using byte means different things between the two languages.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about sbyte...couldn't see the forest for the trees because I was so focused on the Java syntax.

Answer (score 3):

When I compare the 2 result
from Java :

`[72, -73, 52, -38, 71, 56, -116, 101, 105, 19, -55, -65, 81, 70, -31, -122]`

from .Net

`[134, 225, 70, 81, 191, 201, 19, 105, 101, 140, 56, 71, 218, 52, 183, 72]`

I can tell that:

1. They seem alike - .Net is just in revers order (A result of java's internal representation being Big Endian).
2. In .Net result, there are no negative numbers.
3. Comparing the result in reverse order show that `-73` is `183` in .Net

So I think we can say that the result are the same, but need to check that the [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is the same and that signs are maintained.

Can you show the code that print those result ?

Comment: the endianness is for the revers order

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the result from .Net is reversed from the java result, but they are the same values. The .Net byte is unsigned however, rather than the java byte which is signed (contains negatives as you noticed). You can just convert the result that you obtained to a signed byte (sbyte) and can reverse the order as well:

```
sbyte[] finalResult = (sbyte[])(Array)key.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Results in: [72, -73, 52, -38, 71, 56, -116, 101, 105, 19, -55, -65, 81, 70, -31, -122]

It should be noted that the bit representations are going to be the same, so if you are using it as a key for some encryption and manipulating it on the bit level you may not need to get the actual signed byte (sbyte) but it will likely make it easier to visualize the conversion from java to .Net if you do.